# Read html file in variable through javascript in unix (firefox)

Tags: javascript, html

OS: Linux
Browser : Firefox

I need to read a html file content into a string variable through JavaScript ?

Is it possible in javascript ? If yes, Kindly help me with syntax/method to do this

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to use the JQuery library.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get

```
$.get("mypage.html", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do the trick. It's untested but give it a try.

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Another approach could be to query the URL through XmlHttpRequest and read the `response.responseText`

Comment: Can you give me link to more detailed document for above